# port 443 not working on https node express

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, https

I'm running a https example server on `node.js` with express.

I have my certificates and I'm able to run it on port 3000 or 8443.
But I have to put the port on the domain *mydomine.com:8443* and if I want to access the https without saying the port, that should be 443, but this port doesn't load.

I even tried changing the ports on my router to point to a working port, such as ext443->in8443, but that didn't work either. [(ports configuration)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzjc8.png)

So I'm wondering if it's really 443 that I'm looking for?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'ssl/privkey.pem', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + 'ssl/fullchain.pem', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

app.use(express.static('public')); 
httpsServer.listen(8443);
```

i even trdied *mydomine.com:443* and doent work either

Answer (score 0):

443 requires sudo on linux, and admin permissions on Windows, because it's reserved. You can run this program as sudo.
If it didn't helpful, please, attach screenshot

Comment: there is no error text, simply the page doesn't load and the browser tell me that couldth connect. im using 8443 on the server, only the 443 its in the router, in the maping page that i configured the outer port 443 to be the LAN 8443